# Explanation of 1 Corinthians 13:13 (Why is love or charity greater than faith and hope?)

Tags: context

Why is love or charity greater than faith and hope as stated in 1 Corinthians 13:13, 12:31-13:1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faith is the total acceptance of an idea.  It is fully integrated into the way we think, feel, and live.  Normally we don't even think about it any more than we think about our heart beats.  We simply take it for granted, having faith that our hearts will continue to beat.

In the Bible, "hope" doesn't have the modern sense of wishing, as in "I'm hoping to win the lottery.". Rather it has the sense of reasonable expectaion, as in "I'm hoping to graduate from college next spring.".  Hope is the acceptance of an idea accompanied by the realization that it might possibly be wrong.

Similarly "love" is used as accepting an idea even while knowing that it is very likely wrong.  One might give money to a street beggar so that he can use it to buy a nutritious meal or to help him clean up and get a job, but in reality we know that the money will almost always be used to buy alcohol.

---

Getting faith is difficult for many, but once one has it, using it and living with it is easy.  It becomes part of what one is, and one would have to make a conscious decision to deviate from it.  For instance, someone that has repented and accepted Jesus's forgiveness is going to think, feel, and act very differently than they did before, but doing so will soon become natural and easy.

Having hope is easier.  It is often based on our own efforts and our confidence in others and the world around us.  When a Christian buries a loved one they usually have hope that they were saved, but they can't know for sure.

Love is the most difficult way to think, feel, and behave. It requires definite effort to maintain, especially knowing that most of what we do because of it will be useless.

---

Love is "the greatest", because it is the most difficult for us to practice, and because its very existence depends upon our already having hope and faith.

Answer (score 0):

Ones Faith and Hopes can be realised to a completion but Love will lasts forever.

Answer (score 0):

In heaven, faith becomes sight, hope/expectation is realized, while love remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation of 1 Corinthians 13:13 (Why is love or charity greater than faith and hope?)

What is faith, Paul wrote:

1 Corinthians 13:13  (NASB)

> 13" But now faith, hope, love, abide these three; but the [a]greatest
>   of these is love."

Hebrews 11:1 Amplified Bible (AMP)

> 11 "Now faith is the assurance (title deed, confirmation) of things
>   hoped for (divinely guaranteed), and the evidence of things not seen
>   [the conviction of their reality—faith comprehends as fact what cannot
>   be experienced by the physical senses]."

The AMP says that faith is like a tittle deed, when a property is deeded to us we are assured that it belong to us.  Like wise when we have faith in God that he fulfills his promises, is just as good as having a title deed. At the moment we have Love , faith and hope  and when God  fulfills his  promises as mentioned in the Bible, on their  fulfillment  faith and hope will be no more. Love however lasts for ever.